# robot_pose_ekf output to fake_localization

Tags: ros, navigation, robot-pose-ekf, fake-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

I have robot_pose_ekf running and accepting wheel odometry and imu data and it is publishing on /robot_pose_ekf/odom just fine. I was wondering however what the idea of this output was, I was expecting nav_msgs/Odometry as output, because fake_localization takes this as input. Am I conceptually doing something wrong here?

Best regards,
Hans

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/163181/robot_pose_ekf-output-to-fake_localization/) by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1909 on 2014-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

robot_pose_ekf produces a [PoseWithCovarianceStamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PoseWithCovarianceStamped.html) message. This is due to the fact that robot_pose_ekf does not include linear or angular velocities in its state estimate; it only estimates the pose (x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw) of the robot. You should change your callbacks to accept PoseWithCovarianceStamped messages.

If you need an Odometry message, though, I would encourage you to try the [robot_localization](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization) package.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2014-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-11**:
I also have a similar problem. In order to change the callback to accept `PoseWithCovarianceStamped`, should I basically change the type of `base_pose_ground_truth` in [this file](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation/blob/hydro-devel/fake_localization/fake_localization.cpp) ?

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-09-11**:
I'm afraid I'm not familiar with fake_localization. I'd ask this as a new question.

**Comment by [ROSCMBOT](https://answers.ros.org/users/16861/roscmbot/) on 2014-09-11**:
Thanks Tom. I switched to `robot_localization` and it seems to be working with `fake_localization` too